# asp.net ajax - cause validation onBlur event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I wanna to check if login exists or not without postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //validation login exists
        function ValidateLoginExists(source, args) {
            var exists;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/account/userRegister.aspx/LoginExists',
                data: "{'login': '" + args.Value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    exists = result.d;
                }

            });

            args.IsValid = !exists;
        }
</script>

<div>
 <b>Login</b>
 <uc:TextBox ID="txtLogin" runat="server" 
   onBlur="ValidateLoginExists(null,  $('#<%=txtLogin.ClientID %>').val())" />

  <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" 
    ID="cvLoginValidator" 
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateLoginExists" 
    ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Login also exists" 
    ControlToValidate="txtLogin" />
</div>
```

This code works properly only at form submit, but not at onBlur. How do I call  `ValidateLoginExists` at onBlur event?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing EnableClientScript="true" in your CustomValidator. Not sure whether this is the problem or not as I have never excluded it. Will try it when I get home.

Comment: Is there any way to set cvLoginValidator to "isValid=false" using javascript?

Comment: EnableClientScript=="true"  by default. But I just removed onBlur event handler and it's work.

Comment: Ah, true. I should have read the docs. Glad you got it sorted.